# static member 'WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)' accessed via instance reference

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, webview, android-webview

Я пытаюсь в Java классе (во фрагменте) установить свойство `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` у `WebView`. Для этого я использую следующий код:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mWebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        ...
        mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(...);
}
```

И всё отлично работает, но IDE выделяет `mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` со следующим предупреждением об ошибке:

> static member
>   'android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)'
>   accessed via instance reference

Но при этом, если поменять `mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` на `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled`, то дебаггинг не будет разрешён. Как можно это исправить? Или просто использовать `@SuppressWarnings("ALL")` перед методом `onViewCreated`?

Comment: может тут будет полезная информация для вас - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556409/webview-setwebcontentsdebuggingenabledfalse-but-i-am-able-to-debug-the-code-af

Comment: Не может быть разницы в результате вызова статического метода в первом и втором случае. Ищите проблему в другом месте.